# Successfully receive gcm notification but when i click on notification status it opens the activity without any msg

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I created the gcm push notification,when server sends the notification then i click on notification status bar it launches new activity but message is not appear.
And when i open the message receiver activity and sending the message from the server then message appears on screen.

this is my GCMIntentService.java file

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  //  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();


   // Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message);



    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ServerActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ServerActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);



    PendingIntent intent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
   notification.setContentIntent(intent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(number, notification.build());  

}
```

}

this is my ServerActivity.java file

```
public class ServerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;
Controller aController;

static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;

// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

public static String prn;
public static String pass;
public static String notice;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.serveractivity);
     ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
     bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
    //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
    aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();


    // Check if Internet present
    if (!aController.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        // Internet Connection is not present
        aController.showAlertDialog(ServerActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting name, email from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    prn = i.getStringExtra("prn");
    pass = i.getStringExtra("pass");      

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest permissions was properly set 
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
    Linkify.addLinks(lblMessage, Linkify.ALL);
    lblMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


    // Register custom Broadcast receiver to show messages on activity
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {

        // Register with GCM            
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);

    } else {

        // Device is already registered on GCM Server
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {



        } else {

            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.

            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    aController.register(context, prn, pass, regId);

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };

            // execute AsyncTask
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}       

// Create a broadcast receiver to get message and show on screen 
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

        // Display message on the screen
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");         

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "Notice: " + newMessage, 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        aController.releaseWakeLock();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Cancel AsyncTask
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        // Unregister Broadcast Receiver
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

        //Clear internal resources.
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

this is my serveractivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#f8f661"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you set Data to Intent ?

Comment: You are not setting data in the intent. Use Intent#setData

Comment: Thank you Sahil Dave but will you give more explanation by writing code that will much better for me.Where to setdata and from where to getdata?